# A problem with an assumption in a previous lemma for the proof of Silver's Theorem on SCH in Jech's "Set Theory"

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

In the Jech's textbook proof of Silvers Theorem, specifically in the Lemma 8.15, there are an assumption in the beginning of the proof.

First, the [Lemma 8.15](https://books.google.com/books?id=WTAl997XDb4C&pg=PA97) says that, under the assumption that $\aleph_{\alpha}^{\aleph_1}<\aleph_{\omega_1}$ for all $\alpha < \omega_1$, if F is a almost disjoint family of functions   contained in a product of the form $\prod_{\alpha<\omega_1}A_\alpha$ such that  the set $\{\alpha<\omega_1:|A_\alpha|\leqslant \aleph_{\alpha+1}\}$ is stationary on $\omega_1$, then $|F|\leqslant\aleph_{\omega_1+1}$.

(A family of functions $F$ is almost disjoint if for all $f,g\in F$ such that $f\neq g$, there exist $\beta<\omega_1$ such that for all $\gamma > \beta$ we have $f(\gamma)\neq g(\gamma)$).

In the proof of that lemma, we suppose the lemma 8.16, but before that, there are an assumption: ***all*** $A_\alpha$ in the product given above have size at most $\omega_{\alpha+1}$. This is clear for all $\alpha$ ***in*** the stationary set given in the hypothesis. Why we can make the assumption for all $\alpha$?

Thank you for the further answers.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly (and correct me if I don't), you are basically asking the following: »Why in a proof of Lemma 8.15 (which only asserts that stationarily many $A_\alpha$ have cardinality at most $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$) does it suffice to assume that _each_ $A_\alpha$ has cardinality at most $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$?«

Comment: Yes, you are alright, why we can make that assumption without loss of generality?

Comment: [Closely related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/594862/462).

Comment: OK, thank you, in fact, the part of the construction of an ultrafilter relative to the stationary set $S$ was the first idea to justify my problem but, in that case, the analogous order not necessarily is a linear order in all the set $F$ (only is a linear order,say, "modulo the stationary set $S$") and this fact is important in the next step of the proof. How can we construct the ultrafilter in order to avoid that problem?